# Garbage collection / reduce memory usage

Tags: php, laravel, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

If I have code that looks something like this (Laravel code here but it should apply generally):

```php
class SomeClass 
{
    public function doSomething(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $this->doSomethingWithItem($item);
        }
    }

    private function doSomethingWithItem($item)
    {
        $model = SomeModel::make($item);

        // ... some other stuff 

        $model->save();
    }
}
```

So my problem is that, if `$data` is a very large set (in my real implementation it is a generator) memory usage increases linearly with the number of data items.

Since `$model` is a local variable and only referenced there shouldn't it be garbage collected? I've even tried `unset($model)` at the end to force it's release but it has no effect.

How can I use this kind of pattern without increasing my memory usage? Since I'm not storing any data structures memory usage should not increase with each iteration should it?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: weird, even if it were a variable of the class it is being rewritten and in theory should release the memory, if the problem is there.

Comment: here is a nice article about PHP and memory https://www.toptal.com/php/objects-references-php-memory

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `unset()` doesn't force the GC, it just removes the reference. You can call `gc_collect_cycles()` to force it.

Side Note:
Another approach would be to chunk the data, that would also allow for datasets larger than memory.

Edit:
After reading through this another time, you're only trying to get rid of the 'wrapper' (model) of the data. The data still exists in memory because `$item` is what actually takes up memory and is never destroyed and exists in scope in `doSomething()`.

Comment: This code is a simplification. `$item` is an array and I want to create rows of `SomeModel` based on data from `$item`. I don't want to wrap it in a model. `$item` is not the responsible for the memory increase. If I put a `return` statement at the beginning of `doSomethingWithItem()` the memory usage stays low and `$item` is still allocated.

Comment: I don't know what extra data your `SomeModel` class adds, but if you really think that it's still the issue,  call `unset($model);gc_collect_cycles();` This will cause the gc to run every time you call that method, though, so it will probably slow down significantly. You could throw in a flag to make it run every x amounts of times, though.